What is a DC path in the feedback of an amplifier?
I have been told that the circuit below "has no DC feedback path".
I could not find anything about this term and have been confused for a couple of days. Can someone please tell me what that means? What is missing in my circuit below?


You have two feedback paths, and they both look like R1 and C1 here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Potential fluctuations (AC) at OUT will be transmitted just fine through C1, to influence FB, but at DC, the path through C1 has infinite impedance. The long-term average potential at OUT cannot influence the long-term average at FB.
If we treat the op-amp output as just a voltage source with some arbitrary DC potential, we can examine DC conditions for different scenarios:

simulate this circuit
The simulator is showing us the "DC operating point", or quiescent state of the system, its state after all capacitors have charged to their "long term DC voltages". I've changed the DC value of \$V_{OUT}\$ in the two scenarios, and you can see that quiescent potential \$V_{FB}\$ at FB has nothing to do with it. It is always \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}\$ regardless of the DC value of \$V_{OUT}\$. There's no feedback for DC.
Quiescent potentials are important, because they "bias" the op-amp, permitting it to settle in the famous condition in which its two input terminals have the same potential, \$V_{INV}=V_{NONINV}\$. That occurs when there's negative feedback, and is necessary to obtain a controlled, finite gain.
C1 prevents DC feedback from occurring. Nothing the op-amp does at its output can result in a long-term steady equilibrium condition in which \$V_{INV}=V_{NONINV}\$. The op-amp will behave more like a comparator with near-infinite gain than a linear amplifier with precisely controlled, finite gain.
To have a DC path from OUT to FB, the path must not be "broken" by a capacitor. You could solve this problem in a number of ways, such as:

simulate this circuit
As long as there exists a path between OUT and FB containing no capacitors, then there's no problem.
To drive the idea home, I'll build an amplifier with gain −1; but I'll DC decouple the feedback path as you have done:

simulate this circuit
Like before, DC potential at the inverting input is \$V_{FB}=V_{IN}=+3V\$, and the op-amp is unable to change that. Without negative feedback at DC, its output is clamped firmly against the negative rail. Let's fix this, by removing the capacitor:

simulate this circuit
As expected, we now have:
$$ V_{OUT} = -\frac{R_1}{R_2} \times V_{IN} = -3V $$
Also notice how DC feedback has now permitted the op-amp to adjust its output to achieve the equalisation of its two input potentials, \$V_{FB}\approx 0V \$, to within a few microvolts at least.

The output cannot set the DC voltage of the inverting input. Because of capacitors blocking the DC. The output cannot work to do any feedback.
So no matter what input voltage there is, e.g. +1V DC, the output must keep charging the feedback capacitors by drawing current so that the negative input is at 0V potential, and it means the output will go negative until it can't go any more negative.
So what you are been told, the circuit does not do what you want, it's not an inverting amplifier, or any kind of amplifier. It's more like an integrator which stops working when it has integrated enough.

Capacitors = AC
Resistors and indcutors have a DC component to them:

Source: https://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/AC.html
Feedback means output to to input, there is no way for a DC signal (a constant value) to feed back to in input from the output, capacitors block DC. If you were to pass a sine wave however, it would go right through the capacitors.

Thanks a lot, but I still can not understand where should be then? Do you mean maybe a resistor above the series RC feedbacks?

Yes, you need a resistor in parallel with the RC feedback.  It can be a high value, just enough to carry the op amp input DC bias current with a voltage drop no more than your output can tolerate.  This bias current is much higher for a BJT transistor amp as compared to a CMOS amp.

It means there is no DC path between the input and output. Lose C1 or C2, and you will have a DC path. You blocked it with C1 and C2.

I have created a "schematic comic"  to illustrate my answer. I can provide more details if needed.
No DC path

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

DC path connected
No input offset

simulate this circuit

Input offset added

simulate this circuit

Decoupling capacitor inserted

simulate this circuit

Equivalent circuits
High frequency

simulate this circuit

DC input voltage
Real circuit

simulate this circuit
No capacitors

simulate this circuit
Simplified

simulate this circuit

Circuit fantasist - Hi, As explained before, please stop the excessive "bumps" of the post, caused by frequent small edits (e.g. it reached rev 5 in just 37 minutes). Edits must be substantial. Again, as explained before, you can make small edits to the post on your local machine and then submit them all together. Or you can delete the post, make many small edits to it while it is deleted, and then undelete it when all the edits have been done. || Repeated small edits are unfair to other posts on the site, as they repeatedly push other posts down the "active" list. Please stop doing that. TY

@SamGibson, sorry, I am wrapping this up. I am in the middle of something, I am feeling inspired and want to polish it. Mistakes bug me. I am keeping a copy on Google Drive, but it is tricky. Mistakes happen because I work on both my computer and phone through the cloud, and I often lose some of my work. The thing is, I keep thinking I have got it all wrapped up and rush to get it out there for the OP, but then I find more stuff I need to fix. Still, I think the most important thing is what we have written; so please be a little more lenient in these moments.
